# Rails 3: Social Stream - Sphinx Install Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sphinx, social-networking, social-stream

I have created a new app in Rails 3.2.5, ran "bundle", then "rails
generate social_stream:install"

I got the following message:

Sphinx cannot be found on your system. You may need to configure the
following
settings in your config/sphinx.yml file:
 * bin_path
 * searchd_binary_name
 * indexer_binary_name

==============================

My sphinx.yml looks like this:

development:
 enable_star: 1
 min_infix_len: 1
test:
 enable_star: 1
 min_infix_len: 1
production:
 enable_star: 1
 min_infix_len: 1

===============================

I went to: http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/advanced_config.html

and looked for an appropriate config to allow me to continue moving
forward with Social_Stream, but I am stuck at this point.

Does anyone know of a config that will allow you to get pass this
error message?

Answer (score 0):

What operating system are you using?

Have you actually installed the appropriate binaries?

Comment: I was able to run the app regardless of this error. I am looking at their code as well. Not sure where it is used yet or if it is in fact required for specific features.

Answer (score 0):

Install Sphinx on your system. If you are using homebrew you can run the following:

```
brew install sphinx
```